# Use of "If statement" in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

How can we use if statement in robot framework.
I would like to execute keyword only if it satisfies certain condition else it execute other code.

Comment: In case you're wondering why you have downvotes, it's because you did not read the documentation.

Comment: Surprisingly, if you google for "robotframework if clause" or "robotframework if statement", this question is the first hit and the answer led me to the right section of the documentation. I up voted the question for this usefulness.

Comment: Pardon guys, but I googled and this is the first result for me.
Downvote the post owner is quite unfair.
And even documentation is very unclear what's the things can I do.
Ex. I want to approach `Run Keyword If A!=B || B!=C || C!=D`
It doesn't define such example anywhere. And from what I tried I got error from condition clause I wrote.

Answer (score 23):

This is described in the [Robot Framework User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html) under the section [Conditional Execution](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#conditional-execution), where it mentions [Run Keyword If](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If) and [Run Keyword Unless](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20UnlesT) among other solutions. Documentation for these can be found in the documentation for the [BuiltIn keyword library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html).

Here is a brief example:

```
*** Test cases ***
| Example
| | ${result}= | Set variable | 42
| | Run keyword if | "${result}" == "42"
| | ... | log | the result is 42
| | ... | ELSE 
| | ... | log | the result is NOT 42
```

Comment: When I use Else, it shows following error.
"'Else' is a reserved keyword" how to solve this??

Comment: @user3068846: that likely means you forgot the continuation characters ("..."), ELSE works when used correctly.

Comment: Thank you, continuation helps.

Answer (score 2):

With robot 4.0 we also have native if else support

```
IF  '${status}' == 'true'
    ${i}  Set Variable  10
    log to console  inside if
ELSE IF  '${status}' == 'false'
    ${i}  Set Variable  20
    log to console  inside else if
ELSE
    ${i}  Set Variable  30
    log to console  inside else
END
```

Comment: cf https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#if-else-syntax

Answer (score 0):

In case multiple keywords need to be executed on the IF branches, this is the syntax:

```
${result} =   Set variable   42
Run keyword if   "${result}" == "42"   Run Keywords
...   log to console   First
...   AND   log to console   Second
...  ELSE   Run Keywords
...   log to console   Else First
...   AND   log to console   Else Second
```